# Is it possible to get the return type contained in a MethodCallExpr using JavaParser?

Tags: java, exception, types, javaparser

Suppose I have the following snippet of code

```java
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        if (yes(1) == true) {
            System.out.println("yep");
            //do something
        }
        List <Integer> myList = new ArrayList();
        if (myList.size() > 1) {
            // do something
        }
        if (myList.isEmpty() == true) {
            //do something else 
        }

    }

    static boolean yes(int choice) {
        if (choice == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I intend to find out the values returned by the statement `myList.isEmpty()` in the if statement. I could evaluate the value of the variable returned by `yes()` which is a `boolean` , using `calculateResolvedType()` method in javaparser. When i tried to evaluate the value returned by `myList.isEmpty()`, it throws an `UnsolvedSymbolException`, though the types of both `myList.isEmpty()` and `yes()` are `MethodCallExpr`. Could you please help me how to get the value returned by a `MethodCallExpr`, when the method is called from a non static context ?

Here is what I tried so far:

```java
public void avoidBooleanIfComparison() throws IOException {
    ParserConfiguration config = new ParserConfiguration();
    config.setSymbolResolver(new JavaSymbolSolver(new ReflectionTypeSolver(false)));
    StaticJavaParser.setConfiguration(config);

    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/OptimiserInput.java");

    CompilationUnit cu;
    try {
        // parse the file
        cu = StaticJavaParser.parse(( in ));
    } finally { 
        in .close();
    }
    for (BinaryExpr bex: cu.findAll(BinaryExpr.class)) {
        System.out.println("Binary expression= " + bex.toString() + " left= " + bex.getLeft());
        if (bex.getLeft() instanceof MethodCallExpr) {
            Expression mce = bex.getLeft();
            System.out.println("Trying to calculate type from " + mce.toString());
            String type = mce.calculateResolvedType().describe(); // here is where the exception occurs
            System.out.println("Type is " + type);
            if (type.equals("boolean") && ((bex.getRight().toString().equals("true")) || (bex.getRight().toString().equals("false")))) {
                System.out.println("avoid evaluating boolean in IfComparsion");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I aim to first isolate all BinaryExpr and then , if the left of it is a MethodCallExpr, then I aim to check the right . And if both are booleans, then I have to print, "Avoid Comparisons when LHS is Boolean".
Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your sample code does not compile. This is a prerequisite for using JavaParser. You must add the corresponding import to the "List" interface.